# [Error]expected identifier before numeric constant.-setlocale

Tags: c++

I wanna use [`setlocale(LC_ALL"..");`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) but I'm getting these compiler errors:

> expected identifier before numeric constant
>    expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
#include<iomanip>
#include<locale.h>
using namespace std;
class account
{
setlocale(LC_ALL"Turkish");
```

Comment: You're getting errors because you're not writing valid code at all. You have to call a function (such as setlocale) from inside a function - you can't just put it directly in a class declaration like that.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can't have a function call in that context, `setlocale(LC_ALL"Turkish");` is a syntax error. You're missing a comma. Also, are you sure that `"Turkish"` is a valid locale name on your system?

Comment: Well, it is normal in C to separate function arguments with commas, so probably, if you use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");` you'll get a better compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@TheUndeadFish points out in the comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx), the issue is you're attempting to the call the function `setlocale` but you aren't in a function. In C++, you can only call a function inside another function. Therefore, you can call it like so:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
}
```

You can call a function from a class, as long as it's a function of the class:

```
class account
{
public:
    account() { setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish"); }
};

int main()
{
    account a;
};
```

When an `account` is constructed, it will call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");`